# Integration of SAP information with node.js

Tags: node.js, api, soap, bapi, idoc

SAP offers a lot of ways to create API's with external systems. In my case I want to create an interface which allows me to access SAP information with a node.js application. I need preferably a real time connection to update the data as soon as possible once changes occur. I was thinking or rather already trying to use SAP BAPI by using the remote function control in node.js without any success yet (probably will eventually work if I keep trying). My only fear is that I might have chosen the wrong method for my case and I'm just wasting time trying to make it work. Is SAP BAPI the best way or are other mean of integration offered by SAP like Idoc or SOAP better for me?

Answer (score 2):

I think SAP API Hub is what you are looking for. This is a centralized catalog of SAP-available APIs, which you can consume in real-time when properly configured, and via different protocols (REST, OData, SOAP) and via different authentication schemes (Basic, x.509). Read the help before using  [API Hub Overview](https://help.sap.com/viewer/84b35b9c39b247e3ba2a31f02beee46d/Cloud/en-US/b2ce2159cda84e1eaf5aa22329723e2e.html).

If we speak about HANA on-prem, try browsing the [correspondent catalog](https://api.sap.com/package/S4HANAOPAPI?section=Artifacts) for S4HANA, it will give a clear outlook of what is available, and [here is](https://help.sap.com/viewer/68bf513362174d54b58cddec28794093/202009.000/en-US/bb2bfe50645c741ae10000000a423f68.html) the tutorial how to activate them in system.

Look through this blog about APIs, it will give a hint:

[SAP S/4HANA APIs and Business Events on SAP API Business Hub](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/10/08/sap-s-4hana-apis-and-business-events-on-sap-api-business-hub-the-wait-is-over)

If we speak about S4HANA Cloud it is even simpler, as you don't need to do any config tasks, SAP Cloud Platform will do all the stuff, [read here](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/09/sap-api-business-hub-support-for-productive-environment/) how to configure SAP API Hub for productive environment.